# Subset dataframe with userinput shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to subset a data frame based on userinput

```
...
df <- eventReactive(input$button,{ 
  df2 <- read.csv(foo(), sep = ";")
  df2$date <- as.Date.character(df2$date,  format = '%d.%m.%Y') 

  #input$Main2 element of (a,b,c)
  input1<- input$Main2

 #Does not work:
 df3 <- subset(df2, input1 %in% input$Main2_1)
 #Works:
  df3 <- subset(df2, a %in% input$Main2_1)

  df3
  })
....
```

Where `input1` is a single variable name. It works fine if I directly write the variable name instead of `input1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df3 <- df2[df2[[input1 ]]%in% input$Main2_1,]
```